# Updating relationships in ORMs

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, orm

Say I have a web app in which User types have a FavoriteBeer property which references a Beer.  On my Edit User page I can have a drop down to select their favorite beer, and the value of the select would be the Id of the Beer object.

How would I receive and persist this in .net MVC?

My inclination is that using Nhibernate I would have a UserEditViewModel that has Name and FavoriteBeerId properties (for example), and that it would be up to me to construct (or acquire) a User object, set its Name, and grab and set the appropriate Beer from the BeerRepo, then save that object.  But is there any way to simplify this?

It looks like in Entity Framework you might be able to just set the FavoriteBeerId on the entity and save it, but in that case how do you validate the user's input?  Like, if I construct a form post with FavoriteBeerId 99999 but the existing Ids are only 1-10, will it throw a sql foreign key exception?  So it sounds like this boils down to the same approach anyway (hit the BeerRepo to verify there's one with that Id).

Edit: my background for this question is partially motivated by tutorials online that suggest that controller actions should be like 3 lines long and be entirely validated by model binding, but neglect to demonstrate how anything more complicated than a one-to-one relationship would work.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague.  I'll take a stab at it for entity framework. though NHibernate does a lot of the same if not more.

The Entity Framework "Code first" approach allows you to write the code and it generates the database.

Complex Types would allow you to relate one set of "Beer Types" to a table of user selected beer types. You could enforce the relationship and only be allowed to select the value in the Beer types table.

[Complex Types in the EF Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680147.aspx)

-

These relationships can be enforced by in the model

[Data Annotations in the Entity Framework and Code First](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/30/data-annotations-in-the-entity-framework-and-code-first.aspx)